# How to create a char array from a bits information with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bit

I have the following structure:

[image]

I need to create a char array with the information values, I mean, I need something like that:

```
char[] result = new char[]{Information, Information, Information, Information}
```

What is the best way to do that? I do it getting the bytes, next passed to bit arrays, next create a string with the information positions and finally apply the ToCharArray() method on the string with the required information, but I want to know if exists a best way to do that.

```
var oneByteInfo = message.ReadBytes(1);
var oneByteInfo2 = message.ReadBytes(1);
var infoBitArray = new BitArray(oneByteInfo);
var info2BitArray = new BitArray(oneByteInfo2);

var arrayString = Convert.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(infoBitArray[0])[0]) +  
                            Convert.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(infoBitArray[1])[0]) + 
                            Convert.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(info2BitArray[0])[0]) + 
                             Convert.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(info2BitArray[1])[0]);

var result = arrayString.ToCharArray();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow. i really want to do your coursework for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presumably something like:

```
char[] arr = new char[4];
arr[0] = (bytes[2] & 0x01) != 0 ? '1' : '0';
arr[1] = (bytes[2] & 0x02) != 0 ? '1' : '0';
arr[2] = (bytes[3] & 0x01) != 0 ? '1' : '0';
arr[3] = (bytes[3] & 0x02) != 0 ? '1' : '0';
```

Note that there are ways to do this more simply (having all 4 possible combinations of two bits as strings, for example, and just doing a lookup) - but this works in the general case.

Comment: Sorry Marc, but why are you feeding such trolls? There is no effort shown at all, no code, no research. Why should we help them?

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you read all the post, I said and write the way that I do it, but I want to know if exists other better way to do the same.

Comment: Then at least show us what you have done, where it fails, what research you have done, etc.

Comment: @gemr1423 Patrick does have a point that the question could better show what you're doing... it is certainly very borderline *at best*; personally I was content that the *words* conveyed at least an attempt, but code would have been better. Asking a question in this way will provoke a negative response, as seen here.

Comment: As Marc said. It feels like we are supposed to do your homework for you. That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was added the code of the solution that I do